# One uppercase letter validation regex

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am working on a regex validation for an alphanumeric character with a length of 4 but contains only one Uppercase letter.

This is the code I have:

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

However, it does not perform the check correctly. How can I do it?

Comment: Try being more elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern like this,

```
@"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be enough for you

```
@"^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{4}$"
```

Or if you want to give minimum and maximum length then use below snippet

```
@"^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,15}$"
```

Here 4 would be the minimum length and 15 would be maximum length for your string

Answer (score 0):

If you need to differentiate upper- and lowercase letters, you need to remove `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` option. It removes the differentiation between the lower and upper case.

Once you remove it, the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/bR4wN1/2) (if you need to support Unicode letters):

```
@"\\A(?=\\D*\\d)(?=\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}\\P{Lu}*\\z)[\\p{L}\\d]{4}\\z"
```

Or just ASCII:

```
@"\\A(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*\\z)[A-Za-z\\d]{4}\\z"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bR4wN1/3)

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [
NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\A(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*\\z)[A-Za-z\\d]{4}\\z" 
   options:0 
   error:&error];
```

Regex breakdown:

- `\A` - unambigous start of string
- `(?=\D*\d)` - check if there is at least 1 digit after 0 or more non-digits (`\D*`)
- `(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*\z)` - check if there is ONLY 1 uppercase letter (`\p{L}`) in-between 0 or more any characters other than uppercase letters (`\P{Lu}`)
- `[\p{L}\d]{4}` - exactly 4 characters that are either a letter (lower- or uppercase) or a digit.
- `\z` - match unambigous end of string.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/9M8d3n) resulting in "yes":

```
NSString * s = @"e3Df";
NSString * rx = @"\\A(?=\\D*\\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*\\z)[A-Za-z\\d]{4}\\z";
NSPredicate * predicat = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", rx];
if ([predicat evaluateWithObject:s]) {
    NSLog (@"yes");
}
else {
    NSLog (@"no");
}
```